# Parameter region for existence of solutions of equation

Tags: r, data-visualization, mathematical-statistics, ggplot2

How does one plot the set S of parameter region of equations using r?. My problem is that I have one equation with 2 variables defined by $g(x,a,b) = 0$ and I want to plot the set of $(a,b)$ where the solution exists.

The specific example I am interested in is the following:

$$(F(x) - a)f^2(x) + \left(\frac{F^2(x)}{2} - a F(x) + \left(\frac{a^2}{2} + b\right)\right)f^\prime(x)=0.$$

where $F$ is the cumulative function of a normal distribution of mean=0 and sd=1, $f$ the density function of the normal, and $f^\prime$ is the first derivative of $f$.

My goal is to construct the region (surface) $S$ where

$$S = \{(a,b)\in [0,1]^2\ |\text{ a solution }x\text{ of the equation exists and belongs to }[0,1]\}. $$

```
E<-function(a,u) {  
((a-u)*(dnorm(q(u),m,s, log = FALSE))/(qnorm(u)))-((qnorm(u))^2)/2 +a*qnorm(u)-(a^2)/2 
}
a <- u <- seq(0,1,0.01)
z <- outer(a,u,E)
b<-seq(0,1,0.001)
contour( x=a, y=a, z=z,levels=b, las=1, drawlabels=FALSE, lwd=3,xlab="a", ylab="x")
```

Please help me here. I hope this can teach me more. Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. But I have 2 remarks or comments :                                                                  Remark 1 : I made a mistake $u=F(x)\in[0,1]$  but $x = N(0,1)$ so $x$ is not restricted in $[0,1]$. So is it possible for you to propose the code that you used in Mathematica such that I can try to adapt it.

Remark 2 : I did also a simulation using Mathematica and I get the 3D picture of my equation but it was not possible to get the projection to get S. This is the code I used :

```
f[u_] := Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], u]
g[u_]:=PDF[NormalDistribution[0,1],f[u]]
h[u_, a_, e_] := (u - a)*((g[u])^2) + ((u^2)/2 - a*u + (a^2)/2 + e)*f[u]*g[u]
ContourPlot3D[h[u, a, e] == 0, {a, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}, {e, 0, 1}]
```

Then I get this picture :

[image]

So is there way to get the projection from this picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address the general question, consider using a tool that is well adapted to such calculations and visualizations, such as *Mathematica.*  (This was used to plot the first two and last two figures below.)

This particular question is amenable to further analysis which enables `R` to display $S$: for each $x\in [0,1]$, we can plot the subset of $S$ it determines (which is a curve).  By choosing a visually dense collection of such $x$, the collection of these curves limns the entire region $S$.

---

Begin the analysis by rewriting the defining equation in the form

$$b = -\frac{1}{2} a^2 + u(x) a + v(x)$$

where (assuming $x\ne 0$)

$$u(x) = f(x)^2/f^\prime(x) + F(x)$$ and $$v(x) = -\left(F(x) f(x)^2/f^\prime(x) + \frac{1}{2}F(x)^2\right).$$

In the $(a,b)$ plane these equations describe similar parabolae having their vertexes at $(u(x), v(x) + u(x)^2/2).$

[image: Figure 1]

*In this figure some of the parabolae are drawn in gray.  The locus of their vertexes is traced by the thick red curve.  The region $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ is shown as a gray square.  $S$ is the portion of the gray square overlapped by the shaded blue region.*

The region $S$ comprises most of the left half of the unit square ($a\le 1/2$), less a small region at the bottom, together with pieces of some parabolae at the bottom.  The next figure examines that lower region in more detail.

[image: Figure 2]

The piece missing from $S$ in the left half of the unit square lies below the parabola $b = -\frac{1}{2}a^2 + u(1)a + v(1)\approx -\frac{1}{2}a^2 + 0.599374 a - 0.15035.$  The part of $S$ in the right half of the unit square (where the curves seem to overlap) is bounded by the envelope of these parabolae; it is difficult to derive any simple formula for its boundary.

---

#### `R` code

Begin with a function `f` to compute values along a parabola given by $x \ne 0$:

```
f <- function(a, x) {
  F <- pnorm(x)
  f0 <- dnorm(x)
  f1 <- -x * exp(-x^2 / 2) / sqrt(2 * pi)
  return(-1/2 * a^2 + (f0^2/f1 + F)*a - (F*f0^2/f1 + F^2/2))
}
```

Because interest lies in $0\le a\le 1$, `a` typically will be a sequence of numbers in this range; `f` returns the ordinates of the parabola lying above this sequence.

Use this iteratively to draw the parabolae.  The vertical line $a=\frac{1}{2}$ (corresponding to $x=0$) needs to be drawn separately because it is not the graph of a function of $a$.

```
n.mesh <- 64
mesh <- seq(0, 1, length.out=n.mesh)
colors <- hsv(mesh, .8, .9, 2/3)
plot(c(0,1), c(0,1), type="n", xlab="a", ylab="b")
rect(0,0,1,1, col=gray(0.96))

for(i in n.mesh:2) {
  x0 <- mesh[i]
  curve(f(x, x0), add=TRUE, col=colors[i])
}
abline(v=1/2, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), col=colors[1])
```

[image: Figure 3]

---

#### Appendix: Brute Force Code

In *Mathematica* a brute-force (but somewhat efficient) way to find a *subset* of $S$, when the function $x\to g(x,a,b)$ is continuous for all $(a,b)\in[0,1]^2$, checks whether this function changes sign between $x=0$ and $x=1$.  Begin by defining $g$:

```
fF[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[], x];
f[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[]][x];
f1[x_] := Evaluate[D[f[y], y] /. y -> x];
g[x_, a_, b_] := (fF[x] - a) f[x]^2 + (fF[x]^2/2 - a fF[x] + (a^2/2 + b)) f1[x];
```

Here is the solution (which plots quickly):

```
RegionPlot[g[0, a, b] g[1, a, b] < 0 , {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

In general some analysis is required to assure that this covers all of $S$.  That analysis can be assisted by plotting contours of $(a,b)\to g(x,a,b)$ for various values of $x$ of interest:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[g[x, a, b] == 0, {x, Range[0, 1, 1/64]}], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Figure 4]

To the extent you can trust `R` to produce accurate contour plots, a similar solution is available for it.